# If a HTML string has certain characters then hide an element on the page

Tags: jquery, string

So I did find some similar questions with answers, but couldn't get it to work.

I want to check if the string inside a `<span class="productID">` tag STARTS with the letters "EP", if so then hide a button element on the page. So it would only check the first two characters within the tag and disregard the rest.

Comment: yes, the string within that span tag, for example, <span class="productID">EP12345</span>, so since this contains EP in the front, then it would hide a button

Comment: Yeah, figured out. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if ($('.productID').text().substring(0, 2) == "EP") {
   $('#targetButton').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringvar = $('span .productID').text();
if ((stringvar.charAt(0) == "E") && (stringvar.charAt(1) == "P"))
{
    $('#button').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rSVve/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($(".productID"),function(){
        if($(this).text().substring(0, 2) == "EP"){ 
          $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```